# splitting up lines of a file using python

Tags: python

I have a file containing:

```
   0.0000  6 G01 G03 G04 G11 G28 G32
42.750    38.750    44.250    36.000    39.000    42.750
```

I am trying to split up the 2nd and 3rd line so that i have a list of:

`(0.0000, 6, G01, G03, G04, G11, G28, G32)` for the 2nd line and,

`(42.750, 38.750, 44.250, 36.000, 39.000, 42.750)` for the 3rd line.

so far I have:

```
for line in file:
    if ('G') in line:
        sats = line.split("/t")  
    elif ('-1') in line:
        epoch = line.split("/t")
```

However they are not being split up properly and all that i get is:

```
sats= ['   0.0000  6 G01 G03 G04 G11 G28 G32\n'  ]
epoch= ['     1.0000 -1\n']
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: note: this has to be generic so that i can use it for multiple lines in the file, (the lines have the same format but different values)

Comment: A forward slash is not the same thing as a backslash.

Comment: why are you checking '-1' in line ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `split("/t") by split()`.

Comment: thanks, I realise my question was not clear, and did not include the necessary info. I replaced it with split() and it seems to work, Thanks.

Comment: Glad that this helped you